# Solspace super search excerpt not working

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I have the following tag:

```
{exp:super_search:results
                orderby="date"
                paginate="both"
                limit="20"

            }

                <h3><a href="{page_url}">{title}</a></h3>
                <p>{if excerpt}{excerpt}{if:else}No excerpt available.{/if}</p>

                 ....
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

I have the correct excerpt field selected in the channel settings, cleared the cache, reindexed, etc. Still nothing appearing here. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of Super Search are you using? What version of EE are you using? Have you tried just outputting `{excerpt}` (no conditionals)? Is the field set for the excerpt also set to be searchable?

Comment: I'm using EE 2.8.1 Super Search 2.1.4. Outputting just {excerpt} doesn't generate anything and all the fields are searchable.

Comment: Short of asking if there's actually any text in your custom field associated with the excerpt, we would have to dig deeper. Feel free to file a support ticket at http://support.solspace.com/ and please mention this thread. We'll try to come back here with a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, both the Super Search and the native EE Simple Search form had the issue. Here is the explanation and solution:

Your channel preferences indeed had a custom field set as your excerpt field, but this setting was likely not registered in the database. Re-saving the channel preferences should save the excerpt value in the EE database, and excerpts should appear in your results.

Repeat this for each channel that might be causing issues.